# Does the extra 1d6 from Hex get added to each individual ray of Scorching Ray?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage

If I use *Hex* (PHB, p. 251) on a target and then hit it with all three rays of *Scorching Ray* (PHB, p. 273), do I add the extra 1d6 necrotic damage to *each* ray that hits, or do I only add a single 1d6 to the total sum of all rays?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you'll deal an extra 1d6 with every ray that hits. *Hex* says that:

> You deal an extra 1d6 necrotic damage to the target whenever you hit it with an attack.

And *Scorching Ray* says that you:

> Make a ranged spell attack for each ray. On a hit, the
>   target takes 2d6 fire damage.

Finally, to make it really clear that all 3 rays count as separate attacks, we have the following advice from the Player's Basic Rules:

> If there’s ever any question whether something you’re
>   doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you’re
>   making an attack roll, you’re making an attack.

So yes, each ray of *Scorching Ray* is an individual attack, and they will all trigger *Hex* separately if they hit the target.

Comment: Looks like this answers my question on if Magic Missile procs with Hex. Good to know!

Comment: @RoiRoiHe'sOurBoy Yep, Magic Missile doesn't involve an attack, so it can't proc Hex at all.

Comment: @Miniman ...but *Magic Missile*  **IS** an attack. In fact, it's actually 3 separate, simultaneous attack hit events.

Comment: @aaron9eee No, it's not. You can tell by the way it doesn't use the word "attack" anywhere in its description.